# I want to add an exit alert dialogue with ads on my app

Tags: android

I want to alert dialogue with ads on my app.

I am new to android development anybody please help me.
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342157/2633909

Comment: @DKV sir i want exit confirmation dialogue with ads

Comment: Create something like this. You can add whatever the layout u want.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dialog fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment) and provide a custom layout for the fragment with the ads placed as you like